# Do I understand React memoization correctly?

Tags: reactjs, memoization

I’ve read the documentation about memoization techniques in React and have a feeling that I understand them correctly.
However, I see projects where useMemo and useCallback are applied in different ways.

I would like to confirm that I’m not missing anything, so I will describe my understanding below. Please, tell me if this makes sense or correct me if I’m wrong :)

## useMemo

This hook is used to cache the result of some calculation between re-renders.

```
const cachedValue = useMemo(() => calculateValue(), dependencies)
```

It means that after the first run, the cachedValue is saved in memory and returned on subsequent renders without any calculations if dependencies remain the same. The `cachedValue` object on the will be the same (same reference) and would return `true` on `Object.is()`.
Memoizing results of expensive computations improves performance because they are not calculated even if the component is re-rendered, but at the cost of running the hook itself. *(Not sure about that)*
Additionally, it is used to prevent re-renders when passing these values as props to a component memoized with React.memo(Component) or as dependencies to useEffect hook.

## useCallback

This hook caches the function definition (not the result of its work) between re-renders.

```
const cachedHandler = useCallback(() => { doSomething(); }, dependencies);
```

The function is defined and saved (but not called) in the variable on the first run, and the same definition is returned on subsequent re-renders if dependencies remain the same.
Since the function is not called when this hook is used and no results are cached, there are no immediate performance gains. *(Not sure about that)*
The benefit is only when this cached function is passed as a prop to a component memoized with React.memo(Component) or as a dependency to useEffect.
When a memoized function is passed as a prop inside an inline function (`<Component onSomething={() => cachedHandler()} />` there are no performance gains since a new anonymous function is created and passed every time. *(Saw this usage a few times)*.

## React.memo

A component wrapped in `React.memo` is cached and skips re-renders as long as its props remain the same. There is no need to memoize primitive values (strings, for example), but for objects and functions, you need to apply either useMemo or useCallback hooks.

## General notes

A lot of projects and developers wrap values and functions in these hooks prematurely either by convention or as a precaution ("if we memoize everything, there is no need to think about it in the future and the cost is not so high").
The documentation and React developers advise against using these hooks until it is necessary (gives measurable performance gains) as using them is not free and adds cognitive complexity (harder to read and follow the code).

This description does not cover all the cases, but can be applied to most simple cases.

Comment: `useCallback` is simply returns a cached function that uses `useMemo`.

Comment: @max, your summary looks good to me